# PHP new page in same file?

Tags: hyperlink, php

I'm working on a PHP project and I need some help. I need to work with one php file and have multiple links on that php page. If a user clicks on one it will show phpinfo(); for example.

So how can I have a link on that one php page that shows that instead of what is usually shown?

Comment: Please put some thought into your question as it did not make sense.

Comment: I cant think of a better way to explain it. I just want on my PHP page a link. If you click the link it brings you to a new page that shows phpinfo(); but without changing to a different PHP file.

Comment: Do you want to do this without reloading the page?

Comment: Yes. I just want it to hide everything else and show phpinfo

Comment: btw, it's insanely insecure to allow anyone to click a link to view `phpinfo()`!  that's a hacker's dream target

Comment: you can't hack a server with just the info in phpinfo()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very basic example:

```
<a href="index.php?page=phpinfo">phpinfo</a>

<?php

if($_GET['page']=='phpinfo'){
phpinfo();
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a URL query parameter.  Something like `/mypage.html&showphpinfo=true`

At the beginning of your php file, check for that parameter, and if it exists, show the output of `phpinfo()` instead of doing everything else.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for cannot be done by PHP alone.

due to these two comment:

> Do you want to do this without reloading the page? – Hailwood
>   
>   Yes. I just want it to hide everything else and show phpinfo – AustinM

It sounds like you are looking for is [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29).

If so you might want to get friendly with a javascript framework such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com).

Check out [this link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for information on using jQuery's built in Ajax functionality.

Comment: @Dagon, He stated above in the comments that he wants it done without reloading the page, Hence, Ajax. yes?

Comment: ok, fair enough, although technically you are reloading the page, the human visitor  just dosen't know about it.